# MVC Route with Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have tblStudent with list of students.

I'm displaying this list by using the following action: `domain/students/index`.

Now I have a list of types of students(Which is user-editable). For example:

Child, Adult, Math, Remote, etc.

I want to filter my student index page by the type, like this:

`domain/students/index/math`  or   `domain/students/index/remote`

Also, when I'm going to refresh the page, I want that domain stay the same, meaning, if, for example I go to edit student it would redirect me to:
`domain/students/math/edit/2` or something similar.

Basically I need an advanced parameter that holds it's state or maybe a different approach.

Comment: You need to create a route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your RouteConfig.cs file :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
       routes.MapRoute(
       name: "StudentList",
       url: "Students/{type}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Students", 
                       action = "Index", 
                       type = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

and in your View :

```
 <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("StudentList", 
                         new{ controller = "Students",
                              action = "Index",  
                              type = "math" //or whatever your parameter is
                            })">Math Students</a>
```

Note: I assume your controller name is Students and your action name is Index. Use Type as a parameter in your Index action to filter students.